# Which english phrase means to work very hard for a short time, and then coast on the results?

Tags: phrase-requests

There is a two-word or three-word English phrase, whose third word may be "coast", that means a style of work / living in which one works very hard and then lives off the efforts of the work for a time, and then works hard again.

I once knew the phrase, but I no longer remember it.

Does anyone know what the phrase is?

Comment: *The Ant and the Grasshopper* –[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ant_and_the_Grasshopper)

Answer (score 5):

I am glad that you say the third word *may* be ‘coast’... because I cannot think of an example where it *is*!

The thought that you describe does, however, sound very much like [***resting on one's laurels***](http://grammarist.com/phrase/rest-on-ones-laurels/):  ‘to be satisfied with one’s past accomplishments and not put forth any further efforts’ (definition at grammarist.com).

The phrase derives from the laurel wreath bestowed to recognise great success in ancient Greek athletics.  That is also the root of the still-current term [laureate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/laureate) (Merriam-Webster), now meaning someone who has been honoured for achievement amongst a much wider range of cultural activities.  (Nobel Prize winners, for example, are termed *[Nobel laureates](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Nobel+Laureate)* [thefreedictionary.com], and in the UK the monarch’s appointed poet is the *[Poet Laureate, as discussed at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poet_Laureate_of_the_United_Kingdom)*.)

*Resting* on one’s laurels means allowing the evidence (not now *literally* a laurel wreath, as a rule!) of outstanding *past* deeds to impress people, while in fact making no further effort at all.  It is frequently used in the negative sense that someone is using past success *to avoid having to bother any longer*.  Sometimes, however, the expression is used to suggest that someone has already achieved (and in some sense *contributed*) *so much* that they can reasonably be allowed to take it easy now, and others might willingly take up the slack.

Comment: I am ever so pleased that some are finding this Answer useful.  I am perfectly content that others feel otherwise, but users cannot possibly _improve_ their activity here if you give no _reasons_ for downvoting.  I can see no obvious downfall in the effort made here.  Is it the research, or the background provided, or what?

Comment: This answer could be improved by citing the source of the quote and not merely linking to it.  Links tend to break over time.

Comment: @CandiedOrange Thanks, that's helpful -- I have accordingly exposed references.  I see a range of referencing styles here, one way or another demonstrating something of a tension between fullness and brevity.  Drawing on experience in other disciplined writing arenas, I am still working on a stylistic balance for SE (or perhaps for ELU in particular).

Comment: I considered this as well (I didn't down-vote), but *resting on one's laurels* is typically a single-cycle version of what the OP wants.

Comment: @Lawrence I was just crqashinh

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't decipher *crqashinh*. Did you mean *crashing*? *Guessing*?

Comment: @Lawrence _crashing_, so got timed-out (didn't know about that)...  _Resting on one's laurels_ can be one life-path, or an available strategy for as many cycles as you like, or a regular lifelong habit at every opportunity. I don't fancy our chances of finding conclusive evidence for or against 'typically', here. I just wondered whether this _might_ answer OP's needs, particularly since we don't really know whether 'coast' even figures. (The voting on this Answer has been really amusing. I have absolutely no idea why anyone objects to this suggestion, but there seems to be a pitched battle.)

Comment: Well, the phrase arises from the context of ancient sports. An athlete wouldn't be said to *rest on his laurels* unless they stopped training. It's *very* hard to return from such a state. Modern usage, as your link suggests, refers to laziness after success. Saying that someone is *resting on their laurels* doesn't suggest the idea of a recurring work-coast-work-coast-... lifestyle.

Comment: @Lawrence Fair enough, but these days the general approach is indefinitely available even if you give up training entirely, as early as you can. Any number of starting-points are possible, but let's say: be a famous athlete and be lucratively sponsored and celebrated; take a break, and then have a popular stint on the talk-show circuit; go entirely quiet until it's tactically handy to release your (ghost-written) book; have a quick TV tour to collect some more praise; get a highly-paid bit-part in a big film sequel; cheerfully disappear again, while the money rolls in; [next thing... etc...].

Answer (score 2):

Well...a related three word phrase ending in 'coast' is
[*'burst-and-coast'*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=orLvpB-EMgEC&pg=PA50&lpg=PA50&dq=%22burst%20and%20coast%22%20definition&source=bl&ots=c6bUkBozio&sig=MVo3qHLoJUCD0knzw9qgk8KNg6I&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjszsDB8-DLAhXCOhQKHblGAkgQ6AEILzAF#v=onepage&q=%22burst%20and%20coast%22%20definition&f=false) swimming in fish, alternating a brief period of swimming with a coast of constant depth or a downward glide. This behaviour is believed to increase endurance, being recruited at speeds where fatigue may occur.

Source: [Mechanics and Physiology of Animal Swimming. CUP, 1994](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=orLvpB-EMgEC&pg=PA50&lpg=PA50&dq=%22burst%20and%20coast%22%20definition&source=bl&ots=c6bUkBozio&sig=MVo3qHLoJUCD0knzw9qgk8KNg6I&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjszsDB8-DLAhXCOhQKHblGAkgQ6AEILzAF#v=onepage&q=%22burst%20and%20coast%22%20definition&f=false)

In transferring this concept to human work behaviours, I haven't been able to source a phrase describing the overall employment pattern outlined by the OP: intensive working on limited time projects, punctuated by rest/recovery breaks financed by earnings from previous projects.

However, U.S. research shows that the 10% most productive employees work  52 minute 'sprints' or 'bursts', then break for 17 minutes before starting work again.

Sources: [National Bureau of Economic Research Working Paper No. 21923. Not Working at Work: Loafing, Unemployment and Labor Productivity, Jan 2016](http://www.nber.org/papers/w21923)

[TIME Magazine. Careers & Workplace, Oct 20, 2014](http://time.com/3518053/perfect-break/)

Comment: +1: I really like this one. It was lurking somewhere in my near-recollection: long ago I found this used (with the fish background) in writing about cycling. It was and is a possible explanation for why I can cycle all day but couldn't run to save anyone's life. Thank you for reacquainting me.

Answer (score 0):

> He is in a **cycle of rapid stockpiling of resources** followed by their gradual usage over time.
>   This resembles a **reverse-sawtooth waveform**, mapping resources vs time, with a rapid rise, followed by a slow negative ramp.

[image: wave image]
<sub>(source: [electronics-tutorials.ws](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/waveforms/tim9.gif))</sub>

**To Stockpile**

> Accumulate a large stock of (goods or materials): *he claimed that the weapons were being stockpiled* – http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/stockpile

Comment: Thanks @glorfindel. Regarding your change message would *broken image fixed (click '**side-by-side** output' to see the difference)* be more obvious  than "[...] *rendered* [...]"

Comment: you're right. That wording is aimed at how it's displayed in the Suggested Edits review queue (the script operates networkwide), but for sites like this it should be as you describe.